# Replace dynamic links with php

Tags: php, regex

I wan to replace dynamic links in text with text like:
if the links are

```
<a href="show.php?id=3">Number three</a>
<a href="show.php?id=4">Number four</a>
<a href="show.php?id=1">StackOverflow</a>
<a href="view.php?id=9">Foo</a>
```

I want this returned

```
Number three
Number four
StackOverflow
<a href="view.php?id=9">Foo</a>
```

What will be the perfect regex for this, I tried handful of regex but they just don't work. 
**EDIT:**

String contains other links like `view.php?id=5` and I don't want to replace them.

Comment: You can use the following regex to capture the contents of the `<a>` tags: `<a[^<>]+>([^<>]+)<\/a>`.

Comment: @IdidntKnewIt please explain the edge case along with an example.

Comment: @AvinashRaj see edits.

Comment: you should have used an HTML parser instead

Comment: How is "Foo" different from the rest?

Comment: @rid `show.php` vs `view.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$regex = '~<a href="show.php\?id=\d+">([^<]*)</a>~Ui';
$output = preg_replace($regex, '$1', $input);
```

Comment: Please note that if the `a` tag contained any sort of formatting not in this regex (eg. an id, a name, classes or any other attribute in any other order) then it would not replace anything. The safer bet is to go with an HTML parser.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Why to complicate, when OP exactly stated his input and desired output? Sometimes I get feeling that people on SO would use extensive DOM parsers to simply replace `<title>` tag's text node just "because we have DOM parser we need to use it". I've provided the simpliest and fastest in my opinion way to achieve it.

Comment: First of all, your solution works for the OP which is fine. Secondly, my comment was to reflect to OP that this has limitations. People blindly copy paste all the time without knowing what the code does. You didn't write *what* the code does, just "do this". That means that in 6 months when this piece of code breaks because there's an extra space between `a` and `href` OP would have an idea where it goes wrong. Thirdly, if you're complaining about your rep for whatever reason, then be aware that I didn't touch it.

Comment: @h2ooooooo well, that's fair enough, but please don't say that I'm here for rep or anything. I'm not even asking why people downvote, because they do all the time, never providing reason, so I don't even care anymore.

Answer (score 1):

```
$html = '
    <a href="show.php?id=3">Number three</a>
    <a href="show.php?id=4">Number four</a>
    <a href="show.php?id=1">StackOverflow</a>
    <a href="view.php?id=9">Foo</a>
';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName("a") as $a) {
    if (strpos($a->getAttribute("href"), "show.php") === 0) {
        echo $a->nodeValue . "\n";
    } else {
        echo $doc->saveHTML($a) . "\n";
    }
}
```

will output:

```
Number three
Number four
StackOverflow
<a href="view.php?id=9">Foo</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a negative lookahead based regex.

```
<a href="(?!view\.php\?id=\d+")[^"]*">([^<>]*)</a>
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yN7mR6/3)

```
$re = "~<a href=\"(?!view\\.php\\?id=\\d+\")[^\"]*\">([^<>]*)</a>~m";
$str = "<a href=\"show.php?id=3\">Number three</a>\n<a href=\"show.php?id=4\">Number four</a>\n<a href=\"show.php?id=1\">StackOverflow</a>\n<a href=\"view.php?id=9\">Foo</a>";
$subst = "$1";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: Your solution is better as this will replace any`name`/`class` attributes also but I don't need it now and Forien's regex does what I want.

Comment: I fixed that up, don't know who did it?